# Erro instalando Composer no Windows 7 64bits com Wampserver 2.5

Tags: composer, instalador, openssl, windows-7, file-get-contents

Eu estou tentando instalar Composer no W7 64bits. Usando o instalador para Windows que o site do Composer fornece (Composer-Setup.exe).

Tenho instalado o Wampserver 2.5 com php5.5.12 e Apache2.4.9. O openssl está habilitado no php.ini.

Eu estou tendo os seguintes erros na instalação:

```
Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed to open stream: operation
failed
Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed to open stream: operation
failed
Download failed: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto
file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): failed to open stream: operation
failed
The download failed repeatedly, aborting.
```

Eu instalei o xampp e WPN XM, mas usando os php.exe de ambos mostra o seguinte erro:

```
Connection Error [ERR_CONNECTION]: Unable to connect to getcomposer.org
Request to https://getcomposer.org/installer failed with errors:
SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify
failed. Failed to enable crypto. Failed to open stream: operation failed
```

Comment: conseguiu resolver o problema? Se sim, posta aí como conseguiu. Estou com problemas semelhantes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tinha conseguido instalar o Composer no W7 até depois que formatei meu PC. Acho que tinha alguma configuração, ou falta dela, que não estava habilitado o SSL.

Após a formatação e reinstalação do W7 Ultimate 64bits com o WAMP 2.5, fiz a instalação do Composer sem problema algum.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você tenha que ativar o ssl no PHP, no seu php.ini, procure a linha:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Remova o `;`, salve o arquivo e reinicie o Apache/Wamp, se a linha não for encontrada, adicione-a.

Comment: Oi Guilherme, como comentei, "O openssl está habilitado no php.ini".

Comment: @LeoFelipe nas variaveis de ambiente PATH, o que está escrito? Fora isto, tem como adicionar o conteudo do seu PHP.ini no corpo da pergunta?

Comment: Não tinha conseguido instalar o Composer no W7 até depois que formatei meu PC. Acho que tinha alguma configuração, ou falta dela, que não estava habilitado o SSL. Após a formatação e reinstalação do W7 Ultimate 64bits, fiz a instalação do Composer sem problema algum. mesmo asssim vlw @Guilherme Nascimento

Comment: Provavelmente @LeoFelipe a versao anterior do seu wamp era 32bit ou voce estava editando o php.ini errado (no wamp tem dois arquivos php.ini em locais diferentes)